# I need to blend CSS shape as background for image, the image should fit in the shape

Tags: html, css

I need some help with CSS. I have the shape, I got the picture. I need to create some kind of mask or background with the shape with HTML & CSS, and when somebody add new picture it should looks like the third picture. I need to automatically fit the person image in the shape

[image: Placeholder]

[image: Person]

[image: Final result]

Comment: Does this answers your question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Answer (score 0):

```css
svg{
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
      <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3wuV.jpg" x="-25" width="150" height="100" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <polygon points=" 50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="url(#img)"  />
   
</svg>
```

Comment: The result is not exactly what I want:

Check what happening with the Inner image

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X7Vn.png